# host xxxx is not allowed to connect to this mysql server vb godaddy

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm having a trouble accessing the database in my godaddy account. I already created a database in phpmyadmin and a user in mysql database

I need to access the database in my godaddy account using my localhost.

But when i run  my code, i'm getting a `host xxxx is not allowed to connect to this mysql server`

below is what i used in config

```
Public consqlonline As String = "server=Website_ipAddress;user=uname;password=pass;database=syncing;Connect Timeout=2000"
```

Comment: set `host` permissions on the `mysql` server for that user.

Comment: @PedroLobito how can i do that?

Comment: Ask godaddy support.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give a privilege to connect the specific database that the application need to connect, via PHPmyadmin >> choose database >> use privileges tab.

by the way i had this problem also and my server was running on Linux, by default the configuration of the server permit connection only from localhost, so to fix that ive edited /etc/mysql/ my.cnf file: changed the bind-address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 (if the version is kind of old you have to comment the "skip-networking" command

Comment: there's no bind address in my my.ini file. Plus i'm working on vb and accessing my database in my godaddy account. pls help me. this is very urgent